# Excel automatic numeration according to ID

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Given following table:

| No. | ID |
| --- | --- |
|  | HA |
|  | PA |
|  | PA |
|  | PA |
|  | HA |
|  | PA |
|  | HA |
|  | PA |
|  | PA |
|  | HA |

I would like to create a formula for the first column to create an automatic numbering where the main number always increments when ID="HA", and the secondary number always increments when ID="PA", like so:

| No. | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | HA |
| 1.1 | PA |
| 1.2 | PA |
| 1.3 | PA |
| 2 | HA |
| 2.1 | PA |
| 3 | HA |
| 3.1 | PA |
| 3.2 | PA |
| 4 | HA |

If it helps, what I have got so far is:

```
=IF(B2="HA",COUNTIF($B$2:B2,"HA"),CONCAT(A1,".",COUNTIF(INDIRECT("B"&XMATCH("HA",$B$2:B2)),"PA")))
```

As you can see I am struggling with the second part, maybe someone can help me out from here.

Comment: which version of Excel do you have?

Comment: To be honest I work with WPS Office, but can switch using Excel 365

Comment: Is it supposed to be text 3.2 or the English way of writing a number 3.2? If it's the latter, you can just add 0.1 to the previous cell if ID is PA and if it's HA `ROUNDDOWN` the previous cell + 1. For text, you can use functions like MID/LEFT [like here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/split-text-string-excel/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `Microsoft-365` you may try `SCAN()` function.

```
=SCAN(0,B2:B11,LAMBDA(a,x,IF(x="HA",a+1,a)))+SCAN(0,B2:B11,LAMBDA(aa,xx,IF(xx="HA",0,aa+1)))/10
```

As per suggestion by @VBasic2008 in comment section, following formula is more simpler and elegant.

```
=SCAN(0,B2:B11,LAMBDA(a,x,IF(x="HA",INT(a)+1,a+0.1)))
```

[image]

Comment: +1 - but on a e.g. German system this fails - as the decimal separator is a comma --> `=SUBSTITUTE(SCAN(0,B2:B11,LAMBDA(a,x,IF(x="HA",a+1,a))) + SCAN(0,B2:B11,LAMBDA(aa,xx,IF(xx="HA",0,aa+1)))/10,",",".")`

Comment: @Ike May be. I do not worked on German system.

Comment: What's wrong with `=SCAN(0,B2:B11,LAMBDA(a,x,IF(x="HA",INT(a)+1,a+0.1)))`?

Comment: @VBasic2008 This is more elegant. I have added this formula to my answer.

Comment: Maybe also add, to cover a 3rd (Else) option, `=SCAN(0,B2:B11,LAMBDA(a,x,IF(x="HA",INT(a)+1,IF(x="PA",a+0.1,a))))`,

Comment: @VBasic2008 Thank you! I thought about nested IF inside scan. Well done!

Comment: Nice answer. I was wondering how you would go about extending the series to (say) 2.10,2.11,2.12.. if that was required - I guess you would have go back to using two scans together and concatenate them.

Comment: @TomSharpe Good point. I will do test by myself.

Comment: Good Solutions @Harun24hr Dada =) Just Marvelous!